# Netflix will no longer play movies after Firefox Update to 89.0. I am running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on an HP 32 bit Probook

Tags: firefox, hp, mate, netflix

Netflix worked perfectly on this machine Until about three weeks ago.  The only change made was to Update Firefox to the latest version as well as install the latest recommended updates to Ubuntu.  Any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you get an error message? What symptoms do you have? Are you connecting via a https connection? Is your Probook really 32 bit? Log into another user account and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: I get an error F7121-3078 from Netflix with a message reading, "Pardon the interruption.  Looks like this version of your browser is no longer supported. Please install the latest version to continue watching."

Comment: I have subsequently installed the previous version, 88.0.1 but get the same error message.  I am beginning to conclude that it may not be the update to Firefox that caused the problem but something else that may have changed.

Comment: Yes, the HP Probook really is a 32 bit machine.  It was purchased in 2008 running Windows 7 and converted to Ubuntu Mate when Window 7 went out of support.  It was mostly being used to make an older "not smart" LCD TV capable of being used for watching Netflix and viewing other online content.

Comment: Did you "Log into another user account and see if you have the same problem." like I previously requested?

Comment: At the moment I don't have access to another user's account but I can log in to my account on a Samsung smart TV and also on another PC running Windows 7 and Firefox 89.0.  The problem thus seems to be something to do with the HP machine and its Ubuntu Mate 18.04 set up.  I have tried to get help from Netflix but they do not offer support for Linux based equipment.

Comment: It may not have been clear from my earlier posts but I can log in to my Netflix account on the HP/Ubuntu machine and I can browse the content, view my Continue Watching and saved play list.  The error message only appears when I try to view/play content.

Comment: The reason that I asked you to log into a different account, was to quickly eliminate something wrong in your normal account. If you don't have another user account, you can create one quickly, test FF, and then delete the account later. Also, in either account, what happens if you use the "Private Window" option (from the File menu). Does that work?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Had a 5 hour power outage today so haven't been able to work on this as much a I had intended but I have tried the following:

1. Using a private window makes no difference.
2. Logging into a different account makes no difference
3. Installing Firefox-ESR version did not help.  The same error message appears the moment I try to play any content.
4.  You Tube content plays normally but another local streaming service also will not play content although Trailers will play.

Comment: Good info! Try booting to a newer Ubuntu Mate 21.04 flash USB (if you can on a 32-bit Probook), and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: I have rechecked and confirmed that the Firefox Play DRM option is enabled but I am beginning to suspect that the problem revolves around playing protected content.  I have checked using my account on a 32 bit windows machine under Windows 7 Professional and Netflix works fine.  

I don't have the expertise to dig deeper and am now out of ideas.

Will try booting a newer version from a flash drive when I have more time as you suggest.

Comment: Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: It does not work in Chromium and Google Chrome is not available in a 32 bit version.

Comment: Time to buy yourself a much newer laptop... 32-bit is long dead...

Answer (score 2):

32 bit Linux is no longer supported by the current Widevine 4.10.2209.1 version and older Widevine versions can no longer get a valid license.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to install Firefox ESR from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

and then launch it using `firefox-esr` command to test.

Comment: I have been busy the last few days but hope to try installing the ESR version and see if this works over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

If the ESR is not what you’re looking for, it may be possible to install an older version like this:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Check for available Firefox versions:

   ```
   apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
   ```

   This will give you something like:

   ```
   Version: 89.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
   Version: 87.0+build1-0ubuntu1
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** These versions may not be accurate. Be sure to confirm with *your* system rather than copy/pasta the steps.</sub>
3. Install the version you would like, for example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install firefox=87.0+build1-0ubuntu1
   ```
4. Block Ubuntu from upgrading the browser again:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold firefox
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** This can create issues with security updates if the package is held for too long. If you choose to upgrade later, you can `unhold`, then update.</sub>